Golang IBM Z (s390x) asm vector instruction element size representation
We can find there are B/H/F/G/Q element size suffix for vector instruction in https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/internal/obj/s390x/vector.go.
// This file contains utility functions for use when
// assembling vector instructions.

// vop returns the opcode, element size and condition
// setting for the given (possibly extended) mnemonic.
func vop(as obj.As) (opcode, es, cs uint32) {
    switch as {
    default:
        return 0, 0, 0
    case AVA:
        return op_VA, 0, 0
    case AVAB:
        return op_VA, 0, 0
    case AVAH:
        return op_VA, 1, 0
    case AVAF:
        return op_VA, 2, 0
    case AVAG:
        return op_VA, 3, 0
    case AVAQ:
        return op_VA, 4, 0

So, what's the element size of B/H/F/G/Q?
Does B mean multiple 8-bit values in 128-bit vector?
Does H mean multiple 16-bit values in 128-bit vector?
How about F/G/Q? Which letter represents multiple 32-bit values and Which letter represents multiple 64-bit values?
Here is the Copilot's answer:
In the context of the Go assembly code you provided, the suffixes B, H, F, G, and Q represent different element sizes for vector instructions. Here's what each of them stands for:

B: This stands for Byte and represents multiple 8-bit values in a 128-bit vector.
H: This stands for Halfword and represents multiple 16-bit values in a 128-bit vector.
F: This stands for Fullword and represents multiple 32-bit values in a 128-bit vector.
G: This stands for Doubleword and represents multiple 64-bit values in a 128-bit vector.
Q: This stands for Quadword and represents a single 128-bit value in a 128-bit vector.

These suffixes are used to specify the size of the elements that the vector instruction operates on. The exact meaning can vary depending on the specific architecture and instruction set.

Ask such stuff on the golang-nuts mailing list as chances are higher to get a useful and informed answer.
